# C# sorting multiple numbers in a list. Sort by second string

Tags: c#

i am trying to make a list of things and trying to so

```
        var l = new List<string[]>() {
                            new string[] { "10945730333", "5"},
                            new string[] { "298543022", "234"},
                            new string[] { "382958320", "35"},
                            };
        var result = l.OrderBy(f => f[1]).ToList();
        MessageBox.Show($"{result}");
```

i want it so it sorts the second number by lowest to highest. so that the 234 is on the bottom. When i do use it it comes up with "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String[]]"

Comment: Why do you think you can interpolate a `List<string[]>` into a `string`?

Answer (score 0):

First, your sorting is incorrect, you should parse the `string` to an `int` otherwise you'll be performing a string comparison which is not what you want.

```
 var result = l.OrderBy(f => int.Parse(f[1])).ToList();
```

Then you can get the result like so:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n",result.SelectMany(e => e)));
```